# jQuery Mobile ajax request

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile

I am trying to retrieve information from a javascript file in my jQuery mobile website.  Ajax is enabled by default, yet when I try xmlHttpRequest.send(), the responseText is the source code for the page rather than a json structure.  The initialize() function is run at pageinit, so my thinking is that the json it is retrieving should exist when called.  Also, initialize() works fine on the non-mobile variant of the site so I think it has something to do with how JQM handles ajax requests.  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        var xmlHttpRequest;
        var json;

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function initialize()
            {
                xmlHttpRequest = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() :
                                 new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");

                if (xmlHttpRequest == null)
                return;

                xmlHttpRequest.open("GET", "pick.js", false);
                xmlHttpRequest.send();
                json = eval('('+ xmlHttpRequest.responseText +')');
            }
        </script>
        ......
    </head>

    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="map-page"> 
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $('#map-page').live('pageinit',function(){
                    initialize();
                });
            </script>
            .....
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might try using Fiddler to see what the traffic looks like.

Comment: Just to be clear -- you're trying to fetch a script dynamically then execute it on the page, right?

Comment: That is correct.  The javascript is generated on the server and contains json.  I want to retrieve that for processing in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery Mobile (and thusly, jQuery), you should consider using [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) -- it handles all of the 'hard stuff' like creating XHR object for you.

For your situation your code would look like this:

```
function initialize() {

   $.get("pick.js", function(data, status, jqXHR) { 
       //when the call succeeds, do something with the 'data' param
       console.log(data);
   }, "script");
}
```

Comment: This results in the same response as before.  The callback function never executes, so I guess that means the request still fails.

Comment: @petfreshman When a request 'fails' that means the actual request gets something besides a 200.  Do you have firebug or fiddler?  Can you tell me what the server tells you when the request fires (if you use firebug, open up the console or net panel and take a peek at the request/response)

Comment: Interesting, when I go to the url directly, it works fine, but linking to it from another page within the app fails.  I am using Firebug and the status says '200 OK'.  I've seen this effect on different forums but every post seems to have a different solution.

Comment: It would probably be best to move whatever code is inside "pick.js" to your page.  That, or you could use require.js or some other dynamic script loading utility to load said script.  Its hard to give you a good answer because I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: After reviewing my server side code, I decided ajax wasn't completely necessary.  But this solution was useful had I continued on that path.  Thanks Plan B!

Comment: Glad to help, and that you got it all ironed out!